# Definition of $\pi_0$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

$\pi_0(X)$, for a topological space $X$, is the space of homotopy classes of maps $S^0\to X$. I suppose here $S^0$ may be taken as the set $\{\pm1\}$ with the discrete topology.

I am wondering, are there instances in which $\pi_0(X)$, is not a set which is bijective to the set of path-connected components of $X$? In particular, what happens when $X$ is not locally path-connected?

This question arose because in some book (Rørdam's) they make a distinction between $X/\tilde{}~h$, the set of path-connected components of $X$, and $\pi_0(X)$. But I was not aware there was a difference.

Here is the relevant excerpt from the book:
[image]

Comment: Note that these are basepoint-preserving maps, so $\pi_0(X)$ is the same thing as "Homotopy classes of maps from $\{-1\}$". A homotopy class of map from a point is the same thing as a path component. (Do you see why?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, these are always the same.  More precisely, $\pi_0(X,x_0)$ is the set of homotopy classes of *basepoint-preserving maps* $S^0\to X$: that is, maps that send $1$ to $x_0$.  Two such maps $f,g:S^0\to X$ are homotopic iff there is a path in $X$ from $f(-1)$ to $g(-1)$, since given any such path you can define a homotopy $H:S^0\times I\to X$ to be the constant path at $x_0$ on $\{1\}\times I$ and your given path on $\{-1\}\times I$.  So sending $[f]$ to the path-component of $f(-1)$ is a bijection from $\pi_0(X,x_0)$ to the set of path-components of $X$.

I don't know why the book you're reading distinguishes the two.  Maybe the intended distinction come from the fact that the set of path-components can be defined without choosing a basepoint, whereas $\pi_0(X,x_0)$ requires the choice of a basepoint (and is then a pointed set, not just a set).

Comment: The last part is exactly the difference - $\pi_0(X, x_0)$ is a pointed set, with a distinguished element. It may be different from $\pi_0(X, x_1)$, namely exactly when $x_0$ and $x_1$ are in different path-connected components of $X$.

Comment: I edited the question to include the section from the book which defines this distinction. Perhaps you can shed some light on that.

Comment: @PPR: I think the author is just mistaken.  With their definition, $\hat{\iota}$ is bijective iff $\pi_0(X)\to\pi_0(Y)$ is a bijection, even if the spaces are not locally path-connected.  (At least, assuming that the equivalence relation $x\sim_h y$ is "there exists a path from $x$ to $y$".)